# Current source controlled via PWM

Tags: current

Trying to simulate a sensor that acts as a current source. This sensor generates 2 current values:

- 10mA (low signal)
- 20mA (high signal)

I will be using an STM32F4 micro - PWM output pin to try to generate these two current values periodically and connect it to the system, so that the system thinks that it is connected to this sensor.

My question is, any ideas on how to generate these two current values controlled via a PWM? What circuitry should be used?

I haven't worked with current sources before.

[image: Sensor Connected to normal system]

Comment: It's probably better to just use two LM317s wired as current sources and switch between them since you only need two values. Or one LM317 with a digital pot if you can find a suitable one. Or LM317 and a suitable analog switch to change between two resistance values. I would switch a resistor into parallel with the first  to get the second value rather than actually swap between two resistors if possible. Should make a smoother change But a PWM current source is basically a buck converter where you monitor the current instead of the voltage in your feedback loop. Stability concerns aside...

Comment: If the "system" has a steady input resistance you could get away with two resistors. One connected to Vcc for 10mA offset, the second connected to a GPIO for the additional 10mA.